# Resetting the state of fragment on tab bar action(not save or restore)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

how to reset the state of a fragment whenever i navigate to a fragment  by tab bar action.
For example: I have two  TABS(A and B), each having 3 fragments.
presently,I am in tab B's fragment no 3.
 - I select tab A 
 - I re select tab B 
expected result should be fragment number 1 of respective tab (B).
what actually it does is , it takes me to previous saved state that is fragment 3.

```
        toolBarTextView  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.toolBarTextView);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

        // Add Fragments to adapter one by one -- For TAB 1
        if (fragmentNo != 1){
            adapter.addFragment(new OpenOrdersFragment(),"0\nOPEN");
        }else if (fragmentNo == 1){
            //from OpenOrdersFragment fragment to move in BookingDetailFragment
            adapter.addFragment(new BookingDetailFragment(),"0\nOPEN");
        }

        //from assigned fragment to move in BookingDetailFragment   -- For TAB 2
        if (fragmentNo == 0 || fragmentNo == 1 || fragmentNo == 2){
        //adapter.addFragment(new BookingAssigned(),"0\nASSIGNED");
        } else if (fragmentNo == 3){
            adapter.addFragment(new 
            BookingDetailFragment("assigned"),"0\nASSIGNED");
        }else if (fragmentNo == 4){
            adapter.addFragment(new PickUpFragment(),"0\nASSIGNED");
        }

//        -- For TAB 3
        adapter.addFragment(new BookingDelivered(),"0\nDELIVERED");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

Comment: are you using setOffscreenPageLimit method on view pager ?

Comment: @Duggu  no sir... how it would be helpful...can you elaborate

Comment: setOffscreenPageLimit(0) on ur viewpager and try ...

Comment: sir i'm naive to android programming .. so my questions might seem silly...
pardon me :) ...
should I override the above mention  method in the viewpageadapter class(viewpage adopter extending fragmentstatepage in my case ) or some where else..

Comment: please add your code where u adding fragment on view pager.

Comment: i've got it but still not working for me...

Comment: viewPager. setOffscreenPageLimit(1);

Comment: You may look at my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59822026)