# Android - How to stop fragment from automatically restoring its state?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have created a whole new project to demonstrate my problem. Basically, my fragment has two `RadioButton`. When onCreateView, I always use `radioButtonFirst.setChecked(true);`. But if I check the `radioButtonSecond` then navigate out by pressing Back button, next time opening it, it automatically checks the `radioButtonSecond`. That behavior is breaking my logic.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WeirdFragment weirdFragment;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        weirdFragment = new WeirdFragment();
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    }
    public void openFragment(View v){
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, weirdFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

**WeirdFragment.java**

```
public class WeirdFragment extends Fragment {
    private RadioButton radioButtonFirst;
    private RadioButton radioButtonSecond;
    private Button buttonReturn;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_weird, container, false);
        radioButtonFirst = view.findViewById(R.id.radio_button_first);
        radioButtonSecond = view.findViewById(R.id.radio_button_second);
        buttonReturn = view.findViewById(R.id.button_return);

        radioButtonFirst.setChecked(true);

        // I decide to set a listener right here, to see what happened to my radio button. So this listener will be removed in my real project.
        radioButtonSecond.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                Log.v("weird", "i got here");
            }
        });
        buttonReturn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(WeirdFragment.this).commit();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_open"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="openFragment"
    android:text="Open"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button_open" />
```

**fragment_weird.xml**

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_button_first"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="First" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_button_second"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Second" />
</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_return"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Return"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

I set a breakpoint at the log statement. That breakpoint, when triggered by user action, the stacktrace will look like this:

```
onCheckedChanged:31, WeirdFragment$1 (com.peanut.myweirdradiobutton)
setChecked:154, CompoundButton (android.widget)
toggle:113, CompoundButton (android.widget)
toggle:78, RadioButton (android.widget)
performClick:118, CompoundButton (android.widget)
run:19866, View$PerformClick (android.view)
handleCallback:739, Handler (android.os)
dispatchMessage:95, Handler (android.os)
loop:135, Looper (android.os)
main:5254, ActivityThread (android.app)
invoke:-1, Method (java.lang.reflect)
invoke:372, Method (java.lang.reflect)
run:903, ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller (com.android.internal.os)
main:698, ZygoteInit (com.android.internal.os)
```

But when that breakpoint is triggered from out of nowhere, the stracktrace looks like this:

```
onCheckedChanged:31, WeirdFragment$1 (com.peanut.myweirdradiobutton)
setChecked:154, CompoundButton (android.widget)
onRestoreInstanceState:522, CompoundButton (android.widget)
dispatchRestoreInstanceState:13740, View (android.view)
dispatchRestoreInstanceState:2893, ViewGroup (android.view)
dispatchRestoreInstanceState:2893, ViewGroup (android.view)
restoreHierarchyState:13718, View (android.view)
restoreViewState:494, Fragment (android.support.v4.app)
moveToState:1486, FragmentManagerImpl (android.support.v4.app)
moveFragmentToExpectedState:1784, FragmentManagerImpl (android.support.v4.app)
moveToState:1852, FragmentManagerImpl (android.support.v4.app)
executeOps:802, BackStackRecord (android.support.v4.app)
executeOps:2625, FragmentManagerImpl (android.support.v4.app)
executeOpsTogether:2411, FragmentManagerImpl (android.support.v4.app)
removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute:2366, FragmentManagerImpl (android.support.v4.app)
execPendingActions:2273, FragmentManagerImpl (android.support.v4.app)
run:733, FragmentManagerImpl$1 (android.support.v4.app)
handleCallback:739, Handler (android.os)
dispatchMessage:95, Handler (android.os)
loop:135, Looper (android.os)
main:5254, ActivityThread (android.app)
invoke:-1, Method (java.lang.reflect)
invoke:372, Method (java.lang.reflect)
run:903, ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller (com.android.internal.os)
main:698, ZygoteInit (com.android.internal.os)
```

So I can see that it is the onRestoreInstanceState checking my `radioButtonSecond`. But I don't know how to prevent it. Things I am considering:

1. Doing my logic in onViewStateRestored. But that is rather a not clean solution.
2. Re-create my fragment everytime I need to open it. But my initializing phase when creating a new fragment is costly, I shouldn't do that.

In my real project, this fragment is like a setting for something in my app, it has a Cancel and an OK button. So, I want the fragment is in its default state every time it is opened because I think, for example, the user might configure many many things, but then press Cancel, then it is reasonable to see all of the views are in their default states, rather than the configured one (maybe this thought is causing my problem, is it a good user experience?)

So, how to prevent my fragment from restoring its state without my permission?

Comment: You may look at my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59822026)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to reset the state of the `RadioButton`s  before the users are leaving the `Fragment` in order to prepare for the case that the `Fragment` is reentered at some later time.

Since you want to have the first `RadioButton` checked each time the users reenter the `Fragment` after leaving it but (I suppose) not when the users just left your app for half an hour and then returned to continue right where they left off, you should use the *savedInstanceState* `Bundle` to make sure the `RadioButton`s have the correct state depending on the situation:

Let's introduce a field `private boolean isFirstButtonChecked = true;`.

Keep the `OnCheckedChangeListener` to track the checked state of the `RadioButton`s using

```
isFirstButtonChecked = radioButtonFirst.isChecked();
```

In addition to that, set the `boolean` to `true` in the `OnClickListener`

```
buttonReturn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            isFirstButtonChecked = true;
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(WeirdFragment.this).commit();
        }
});
```

Now you can save the desired state in `onSaveInstanceState()`:

```
     @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean("FIRST_RB_STATE", isFirstButtonChecked);
}

@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
    isFirstButtonChecked = savedInstanceState == null 
            ? true 
            : savedInstanceState.getBoolean("FIRST_RB_STATE");
    radioButtonFirst.setChecked(isFirstButtonChecked);
}
```

I'm aware that this means adding quite a lot of code. But since you are reluctant to recreate your `Fragment` from scratch each time I suppose it contains more than just two `RadioButton`s. So letting the runtime work for you instead of struggling against it makes this approach cleaner *and* safer than just calling `super.onViewStateRestored(null);` in the corresponding method.

Comment: You don't fully get my intention, so I have just added a few information about my real purpose at the end of my question. However, this statement of yours "you want to reset the state of the RadioButtons before the users are leaving" is actually a hint. Because, initializing default states for views inside onViewStateRestored is a little bit strange experience, because I can see the `radioButtonSecond` is checked and then uncheck immediately. But try resetting view states to their default values when user click Cancel button is actually beautiful.

Comment: So thank you @0X0nosugar, this can be an answer for any general situation, because after some struggling, I think we can't do anything to prevent this behavior of the system.

Comment: @peanut - normally when you press the BACK Button (or leave a Dialog by tapping on "CANCEL"), the runtime thinks it's free to destroy the Activity or the (Dialog)Fragment. Your case is special because you want to keep the Fragment, so you'll have to do a little extra work. There's nothing wrong with doing things a little differently for a reason, but I wanted to show you a way to "go with the flow" as much as possible. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WeirdFragment weirdFragment;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
}
public void openFragment(View v){
    weirdFragment = new WeirdFragment();
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, weirdFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

}

Problem:
You are calling the same weirdFragment object always.
so if you select second radiobutton last time and return , next time it will show second button second selected.

Solution:
Create a new object weirdfragment object always in openFragment function.

Answer (score 0):

Change these lines in your fragment:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.onCreate(null); // <- to prevent the states to be restaured
```